# Deleted IAM user accidentally, any way to bring it back?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-iam

AWS IAM user got accidentally deleted in a bulk delete, which resulted in the service outage. Is there a way to restore a deleted user and re-enable access ID and key as an admin?

Comment: Just create the user with same name. But access keys will have to be new.

Comment: That would work but the new version of the code would have to be deployed, do you think customer support can restore users on their end?

Comment: Support will not help. The keys are randomly generated. And anyway, why do you need keys for you application? Its bad practice to use them, as you experience now.

Comment: Good lesson indeed. It was from a previous employee which is why account got deleted without knowing that it is used by a service. So I'm curious, what is the best practice to give code access to aws, is it through a specifically created IAM user?

Comment: Yes, it is common practice to generate an IAM User for specific applications. Don't be misled by the word 'User' -- just think of it as **permanent credentials**. Alternatively, if the application is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, you should create an **IAM Role** and assign that role to the EC2 instance. The app will then automatically use those credentials.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I would say that best practice is to use roles as long as possible is best practice, if you have a service ran by another company in their account it is an easy way to create an user that they use for their service for the access they need into your account but I think it is better to use cross account roles with an external id. Doing this you wouldn't have had this issue. You could easy just recreated the role if it got deleted.

Comment: Beware that deleting/recreating roles will cause problems if those roles are referenced from resource-based policies, because AWS internally translates the role ARN to an internal ID when creating the policy. When you recreate a role, you get a different internal ID.